# Getting HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:2707/dummy1/dummy2 on Post call from robotframework

Tags: python, post, robotframework

**Getting HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:2707/dummy1/dummy2** When Executing Post call
Input: I'm using robot framework on python and I would like to test the failed scenario, where I pass 4 arguments : Base URL, End Point, empty body , with Authorization Bearer Token for the Post request key word as shown below

```
Library     RequestsLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     Collections
Library         SeleniumLibrary
Library         OperatingSystem

**Post API Request**
    [Documentation]     Post Request call
    [Arguments]     ${base_url}       ${endpoint_uri}        ${jsonBody}=${None}        ${tokenGenerated}=${None}
    Create Session    mysession    ${base_url}      disable_warnings=1
    ${headers}  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json     Authorization=Bearer ${tokenGenerated}
    ${postResponse}=  POST On Session  mysession  ${endpoint_uri}  json=${jsonBody}      headers=${headers}
    ${statusCode} =       Convert to string       ${postResponse.status_code}
    log to console       ${statusCode}
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${postResponse.status_code}      400

***Actual Behavior:**
It fails at ${postResponse}=  POST On Session  mysession  ${endpoint_uri}  json=${jsonBody}      headers=${headers} 
variable ${postResponse} is having "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:2707/dummy1/dummy2" and Test case is thus failing directly

**Expectation :** I would like to get status code as 400 from ${postResponse.status_code} and pass my test scenario*

**Libraries Using:**
requests 2.28.1
robotframework 6.0.1
robotframework-jsonlibrary 0.5
robotframework-requests 0.9.4
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 6.0.0

Can someone please help me to assist on to get status code from this
```

**Actual Behavior:**
It fails at

```
 ${postResponse}=  POST On Session  mysession  ${endpoint_uri}  json=${jsonBody}      headers=${headers} 
variable ${postResponse} is having "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:2707/dummy1/dummy2" and Test case is thus failing directly
```

**Expectation :** I would like to get status code as 400 from ${postResponse.status_code} and pass my test scenario

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [BuiltIn](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#library-documentation-top) Robot Framework keywords to approach this issue from couple different angles. Basically you'll need to run the call, return the value and *ignore the initial error*, because Robot is failing the test on the first raised exception by default.

Based on the issue description I would use [Run Keyword and Expect Error](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Expect%20Error). For example something like this

```
*** Test Cases ***
Post API Request**
    [Documentation]     Post Request call
    [Arguments]     ${base_url}       ${endpoint_uri}        ${jsonBody}=${None}        ${tokenGenerated}=${None}
    Create Session    mysession    ${base_url}      disable_warnings=1
    ${headers}  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json     Authorization=Bearer ${tokenGenerated}
    ${postResponse}=    Run Keyword and Expect Error    STARTS:400 Client Error
    ...    POST On Session  mysession  ${endpoint_uri}  json=${jsonBody}      headers=${headers}
```

This way the keyword will show passed **only** if the error you get matches what is after the `STARTS:`. This method will return the response object as a string due to how the `Run Keyword and Expect Error` behaves.

Comment: Thanks for your information and let me try and check

Comment: Have updated as suggested but unable to fetch status code 400 thereafter from the response.. below is the code and error message post execution

Comment: Updated code as below:
${postResponse}=    Run Keyword and Expect Error    HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:2707/dummy1/dummy2
        ...    POST On Session  mysession  ${endpoint_uri}  json=${jsonBody}      headers=${headers}
    [Return]        ${postResponse}

Comment: Error from the execution:

Error:
.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:2707/dummy1/dummy2
Gateway_TC01_Implement gateway in .net core                           | FAIL |
Resolving variable '${responseReceveied.status_code}' failed: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Comment: I have adjusted the response - The ``Run Keyword and Expect Error`` returns the error as a string and not as a response object from the post request.